# MYSQL What triggers the information_schema data update?

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering what would trigger a mysql information_schema update as I'm running into a wall.

My goal is to read a table's creation time and then present that data to a user. However when I run two mysql querys in php the information_schema doesn't change the creation time. For example:

```
///drop local table
$delete_sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bom_details;";
if(mysql_query($delete_sql)){
    //good
} 
//re-create table to update schema timestamp
    $create_table_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bom_details (
  bom_id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  part_number varchar(86) NOT NULL,
  component_part_number varchar(86) NOT NULL,
  component_level int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'line number defination for parts with multiple sub-components',
  component_qty decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  component_um varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (bom_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
if(mysql_query($create_table_sql)) {
    //worked
}
```

However, if I drop the table in one php script, then create the table again in another php script using the same code posted above, I get a new creation time. Or if I drop the table in phpMyAdmin and run a sql create query I get a new table creation time.

The only other thing I tried was putting a sleep timer in the PHP script to give mySQL a few seconds to register the DROP before proceeding to create the table again, but no luck there.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: How do you check the create time value?

Comment: @didierc  `///Get Last Update Table Time From Information Schema
    $sql="SELECT create_time FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE table_schema = 'part_location'
    AND table_name = 'bom_details'";
   $query=mysql_query($sql);  
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $bom_create_time=$row['create_time'];
    }
    echo 'Last Update<br>'. date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime($bom_create_time));`

Answer (score 0):

After much research and trial and error. The problem was with the mySQL database engine.

It seems pretty simple, if you delete (DROP) a table it goes away, therefore recreating it would make the metadata in the information schema to be new.

Simply changing the ENGINE option from InnoDB to MyISAM does just that.

Here is the complete solution.

```
    ///drop local table
    $delete_sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bom_details;";
    if(mysql_query($delete_sql)){
        //good
    } 


    //re-create table to update schema timestamp
      $create_table_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bom_details (
      bom_id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      part_number varchar(86) NOT NULL,
      component_part_number varchar(86) NOT NULL,
      component_level int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'line number defination for parts with multiple sub-components',
      component_qty decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
      component_um varchar(4) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (bom_id)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
    if(mysql_query($create_table_sql)) {
        //worked
    }

///Get Last Update Table Time From Information Schema
    $sql="SELECT create_time FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE table_schema = 'part_location'
        AND table_name = 'bom_details'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);       
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         $bom_create_time=$row['create_time'];
    }


          echo 'Last Update<br>'. date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime($bom_create_time));
```